# How to stop Navbar overlapping my blog's slider and article headers?

Tags: html, blogs

Blog link: http://confabtest.blogspot.co.uk/

The navbard on my blog is overlapping other elements such as the featured article slider,
and when you open up an article the top of the header and the social sharing widget on the side get partially overlapped.

http://imm.io/voXw

Anyone know how I can fix this?

Here is the code for the navbar:

```
.menu-secondary-container{position:relative;height:40px;z-index:300;background:#000;padding-left:5px}
.menu-secondary{}
.menu-secondary ul{min-width:160px}
.menu-secondary li a{color:#fff;padding:12px 15px 11px 15px;text-decoration:none;font:12px &#39;Oswald&#39;,sans-serif;text-transform:uppercase}
.menu-secondary li a:hover,.menu-secondary li a:active,.menu-secondary li a:focus,.menu-secondary li:hover &gt; a,.menu-secondary li.current-cat &gt; a,.menu-secondary li.current_page_item &gt; a,.menu-secondary li.current-menu-item &gt; a{color:#000;background:url(http://www.colorhexa.com/ff0033.png) repeat-x;outline:0}
.menu-secondary li li a{color:#fff;background:#51ABEE;padding:10px 15px;text-transform:none;margin:0;font-weight:normal}
.menu-secondary li li a:hover,.menu-secondary li li a:active,.menu-secondary li li a:focus,.menu-secondary li li:hover &gt; a,.menu-secondary li li.current-cat &gt; a,.menu-secondary li li.current_page_item &gt; a,.menu-secondary li li.current-menu-item &gt; a{color:#51ABEE;background:#000;outline:0}
.menu-secondary a.sf-with-ul{padding-right:26px;min-width:1px}
.menu-secondary .sf-sub-indicator{position:absolute;display:block;overflow:hidden;right:0;top:0;padding:13px 13px 0 0}
.menu-secondary li li .sf-sub-indicator{padding:9px 13px 0 0}
.wrap-menu-secondary .sf-shadow ul{background:url(&#39;http://1.bp.blogspot.com/-DuEC7hcoyA4/Tuh_aeS2pzI/AAAAAAAABUY/pKXmvzomJkw/s1600/menu-secondary-shadow.png&#39;) no-repeat bottom right}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in your html look at this div which is next to div header-wrapper

```
<div class="span-24" style="height: 0pt;">
```

remove the style attribute on this div. this should fix the issue.

Comment: Thank you so much! Didn't expect such a quick reply. Worked perfectly :)